# ath10k_pci firmware crash

Tags: wifi, firmware

I'm on Linux Mint. My wifi randomly stops working and the pc gets laggy for about 5 seconds. This issue is recent, as I've been using Linux for almost a year now but this started happening a month ago or so

I've tried getting the latest firmware from the repo at [github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware](http://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware), as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973819/wifi-often-freezes-after-17-04-17-10-upgrade#answer-996395), but that didn't work

I've tried the following kernel parameters: `pci=nomsi`, `pcie_aspm=off`, `pci=nommconf`,  and `ath10k_core.skip_otp=y`, but none of them solved the issue.

I've also tried the suggestions in [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205311#c8) and [here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-co/000144425/killer-wireless-firmware-update-guide-for-ubuntu-systems), but had no luck

The issue happens in kernels 5.8.0-55 and 5.4.0-74.

I got these logs from journal -p 3

```
Jun 26 15:16:33 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
Jun 26 15:16:39 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
Jun 26 15:16:42 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
Jun 26 15:16:42 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to reset chip: -5
Jun 26 15:16:42 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Could not init hif: -5
Jun 26 15:16:42 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid 931c5c85-8ba3-4b61-b080-9eb1a53ce38e)
Jun 26 15:16:48 jorgeiszlinux kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
Jun 26 15:16:48 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to read firmware dump area: -16
Jun 26 15:16:48 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes.constprop.0 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: wlp1s0: failed to remove key (0, 8c:5f:ad:56:34:eb) from hardware (-5)
Jun 26 15:16:49 jorgeiszlinux kernel: wlp1s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-5)
```

lshw -C network

```
    description: Network controller
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0200000-e03fffff
```

My laptop is Acer Swift SF315 (AMD Ryzen 7 2700U, Radeon Vega)

Note that the issue occurs in other distros as well, so it's not Mint-related

Comment: had the same issue with ATH10k in my dell XPS 13, at some point just went ahead and replaced the wifi module for an intel one :(

Comment: How can I replace ath10k with an amd module?

Comment: there's no AMD wifi modules. I'm a bit confused?

Comment: I have exactly the same WiFi chipset. The Linux driver is buggy (ath10k_pci), cannot handle the suspend/power save, neither RF kill switch. Workaround could be to turn off the WiFi, then you suspend. After resume, turn on WiFi.

Comment: Dell XPS 13, same chipset, same problem recently :(